# Edit HTML source code generated by WordPress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to identify the location of the HTML source code generated by my WordPress theme. To be more precise, I am trying to edit the style of a tag from the gallery page - which is actually the header of the page.

The gallery is installed as a plugin (`Envira-lite`), so the first place where I started looking for the code was in the WordPress Dashboard under Plugins > Editor. Could not find what I needed in there. I then searched under Appearance > Editor and went through all of the templates - all are php files and do not have the html that I need to edit.

Using `Chrome` Dev Tools I inspected the Gallery page and could find the exact line which I would like to edit Gallery, the big question is, where is this HTML code stored?

I even downloaded the entire contents of the theme via FTP and did a search with Notepad++ for Gallery but no results were returned.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use this plugin to see which template files are being used : https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/ - also, this question is formatted terribly

Comment: You identified what you want to edit in the processed html but then you searched on php files. Keep in mind that you won't find the exact line in there, search for something like specific classnames or some id that may be around.